# Show $\lim_{n\to \infty}{|A_{n}|+|A_{n-2}| \above 1.5pt |A_{n-1}|}=2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, conjectures

> ***Question:***  Let $A(n)$ be a finite square $n \times n$ matrix with entries
>   $a_{ij}=1$ if $i+j$ is a  prime; otherwise equals to $0$. I write $|A(n)|$ to count the number of $1$'s in $A(n)$. Is it true, possibly trivially, and how can we show that
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{|A_{n}|+|A_{n-2}| \above 1.5pt |A_{n-1}|}=2$$

The sequence of $A(n)$'s can be found [here](https://oeis.org/A292918) in Sloan. The graph below illustrates the limit. I believe I have shown the question is true, conditionally using a parity argument along with Bertrand's Postulate.

[image]

> ***Solution:***
>
> It is easy to verify that $A(n)$ has exactly $2n-1$ [skew
>   diagonal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkewDiagonal.html). Two small lemmas.
>
> $\underline{\text{lemma 1}}:$  Observe $a_{ii}=1$ if and only if
>   $i=1$. Consequently $a_{11}$ is the only entry on the main diagonal of
>   $A(n)$ equal to $1$. Note $A(n)$ is symmetric since addition is commutative. So the count of $1$'s below the main diagonal equals the counts of $1$'s above the main diagonal and the two counts combined form an even number. If we remember to add the sole $1$ for the entry $a_{11}$ then there are an odd number of entries in $A(n)$. In particular $|A(n)|$ is always odd.
>
> $\underline{\text{lemma 2}}:$ As mentioned earlier every matrix $A(n)$
>   has $2n-1$ skew diagonals. Let $S_n$ be the $n$-th skew diagonal of $A(n)$. A skew analogue of [Bertrand's
>   Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) shows
>   that at least one of the skews between $S_n$ and $S_{2n-2}$ has all of its entries equal to $1$. Consequently for $n>2$ we have that there is always a  skew diagonal with entries equal to $1$ below the main skew diagonal. In particular $\{A(n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a monotonically increasing sequence of odd integers.
>
> Lemma's 1 and 2 control the growth of $A(n)$ as $n \to \infty.$ By
>   parity check alone as $A(n)$ grows to $A(n+1)$ the count of new $1$'s
>   must be an nonzero even number. Because of this we have that
>   $|A_n|=|A_{n-1}|+2j$ for some $j\in\mathbb{N}$, $j\neq0$. So we have the
>   following from direct substitution
>
> \begin{align} {|A_{n}|+|A_{n-2}| \above 1.5pt|A_{n-1}|}&={\left(|A_{n-1}|+2j\right)+\left(|A_{n-1}|-2k\right)\above 1.5pt |A_{n-1}|}\\
>  &=2\cdot{|A_{n-1}|+j-k\above 1.5pt |A_{n-1}|}\\
>  &=2\cdot\left(1+{j-k\above 1.5pt |A_{n-1}|}\right)\\
> \end{align}
>
> Taking limits we have
>   \begin{align}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}2\cdot\left(1+{j-k\above 1.5pt |A_{n-1}|}\right)&=2+\lim_{n\to \infty}\left({j-k\above 1.5pt |A_{n-1}|}\right)\\
> &=2+0\\
> &=2
> \end{align}
>
> This completes the proof.

Comment: You have posted a question and solution – so what are you asking for?

Comment: ^ I wrote it in the question box at the top of the post: I ask if the limit is true and how can we show it.

Comment: Are you asking for a [proof-verification] ?

Comment: Sort of. I am not sure my solution is correct but I wanted to show the work and  effort I put in to try and solve it.

Comment: Do you have any data for $|A_{n-1}|/|A_{n}|$? How it behaves?

Comment: @See-WooLee it appears to converge to one.

Comment: If you write $|A_n|=|A_{n-1}|+2j$ then $j$ depends on $n$. So it is no obvious (to me) why $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{j-k}{ |A_{n-1}|}\right)$  should be zero.

Comment: Hmm ? My reasoning was $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left({j-k\above 1.5pt |A_{n-1}|}\right)=(j-k)\cdot\lim_{n\to \infty}\left({1\above 1.5pt |A_{n-1}|}\right)=(j-k)\cdot0=0$. Here I use the fact that $A_n$'s are monotonically increasing.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez: But $j$ and $k$ **depend** on $n$. – Or do you claim that there is a fixed $j$ such that $|A_n|=|A_{n-1}|+2j$ holds for all $n$?

Comment: @MartinR I took my comment back and deleted it.

Comment: Unless I am missing the obvious this is more difficult than I thought it would be.